# How to get a logarithmic dependence on $K$ for a follow the leader algorithm in i.i.d. stochastic $K$-armed bandits?

Tags: stochastic-processes, machine-learning, concentration-of-measure

I want to prove that, using a follow the leader algorithm, the problem of identifying the best arm in a stochastic $K$-armed bandit problem with full-feedback, where what we pay is the gap of the action we choose, shows a worst-case $\sqrt{\log(K)}$ dependence on $K$. Let me formalize the problem for those who are not acquainted with the bandits terminology.

Let $K \in \mathbb{N}$ with $K\ge2$ and $1 > p_1 >p_2\ge\dots\ge p_K>0$.

Suppose that $(X_{i,t})_{i \in \{1,\dots,K\}, t \in \mathbb{N}}$ is an independent family of random variables such that, for each $i \in\{1,\dots,K\}$, the sequence $(X_{i,t})_{t \in \mathbb{N}}$ is an i.i.d. sequence of $[0,1]$-valued random variables, where each element in the sequence has expectation $p_i$.

Let $T \in \mathbb{N}$ be a time horizon.

Let $I_T$ be a $\{1,\dots,K\}$-valued random variable whose index maximizes the empirical means of the $X$s up to time $T$, i.e.,
$$I_T \in \operatorname{argmax}_{i \in \{1,\dots,K\}} \frac{1}{T} \sum_{t=t}^T X_{i,t}\;.$$

I'm wondering about how large can be the expected gap
$$\mathbb{E} [p_1 -p_{I_T}]$$
in terms of $T$ and $K$.

Specifically, I believe that it should exist a universal constant $c>0$ (independent of $T,K, p_1,\dots,p_K$) such that
$$\mathbb{E} [p_1 -p_{I_T}] \le  c \cdot \sqrt{\frac{\log(K)}{T}} \;,$$
but, for now, a proof of this fact still eludes me.

So far, I have worked in the following manner:
\begin{align*}
   \mathbb{E} [p_1 -p_{I_T}]
&=
   \sum_{j =2}^K (p_1 -p_{j})\mathbb{P} [I_T = j]
\le
   \sum_{j =2}^K (p_1 -p_{j})\mathbb{P} \bigg[\max_{k \in \{1,\dots,K\}} \frac{1}{T} \sum_{t=1}^T X_{k,t} = \frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^T X_{j,t} \bigg]
\\
&\le
   \sum_{j =2}^K (p_1 -p_{j})\mathbb{P} \bigg[ \frac{1}{T} \sum_{t=1}^T X_{1,t} \le \frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^T X_{j,t} \bigg]
\\
&=
   \sum_{j =2}^K (p_1 -p_{j})\mathbb{P} \bigg[ \frac{1}{T} \sum_{t=1}^T \big((X_{1,t}-p_1)+(p_j-X_{j,t})\big) \le p_j - p_1 \bigg]
\\
&
\le
   \sum_{j =2}^K (p_1 -p_{j}) \cdot \exp\bigg(- \frac{(p_1-p_j)^2}{32}\cdot T\bigg)
\;,
\end{align*}
where the last inequality follows from Hoeffding's inequality.
Now, this last term is maximized picking $p_2 = \dots = p_K = p_1 - \frac{4}{\sqrt{T}}$, which yields the worst case bound of:
$$\mathbb{E} [p_1 -p_{I_T}] \le \frac{4}{\sqrt{e}} \cdot \frac{K-1}{\sqrt{T}},$$
which has the right dependence on $T$ but it is sloppy in $K$ (to get the desired $\sqrt{\log(K)}$ dependence w.r.t. $K$).

Does anyone have a better idea of how to get the improvement dependence on $K$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here an approach relying on the symmetrization trick (I'm still wondering if we can get home with a simpler approach).

Let $(X_{i,t}')_{i \in \{1,\dots,K\},t\in\mathbb{N}}$ another process with the same distribution as $(X_{i,t})_{i \in \{1,\dots,K\},t\in\mathbb{N}}$, which is also independent of $(X_{i,t})_{i \in \{1,\dots,K\},t\in\mathbb{N}}$. Then:
\begin{align*}
   \mathbb{E} [p_1 -p_{I_T}]
&=
      \mathbb{E} \bigg[\frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^{T} X_{1,t} - \frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^{T} X_{I_T,t} +\frac{1}{T} \sum_{t=1}^{T} X_{I_t,t} -p_{I_T}\bigg]
\\
&\le
   \mathbb{E} \bigg[ \frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^{T}X_{I_t,t} -p_{I_T}\bigg]
\\
&=
   \mathbb{E} \bigg[\sum_{i \in \{1,\dots,K\}}\bigg(\frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^{T} X_{i,t} - \frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^{T} X_{i,t}'\bigg)\mathbb{I}\{I_T=i\}\bigg]
\\
&\le
\mathbb{E}\bigg[\sup_{i \in \{1,\dots,K\}}\frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^{T} (X_{i,t}-X_{i,t}')\bigg]
=: \mathbb{E}\bigg[\sup_{i \in \{1,\dots,K\}}Y_i\bigg]
\end{align*}
Now, since each $Y_i$ is zero-mean $\frac{\sigma^2}{T}$-subgaussian random variable for $\sigma = 1$  (since for each $i \in \{1,\dots,K\}$ and each $t \in \mathbb{N}$ the random variables $X_{i,t}$ and $X'_{i,t}$ are $[0,1]$-valued and they have the same expected value), we obtain that for each $\lambda > 0$,
\begin{align*}
   \exp\bigg(\lambda \mathbb{E}\bigg[\sup_{i \in \{1,\dots,K\}}Y_i\bigg]\bigg)
&\le
   \sum_{i=1}^K \mathbb{E} \bigg[ \exp(\lambda \cdot Y_i) \bigg]
\le
    K \cdot \exp\bigg(\frac{\lambda^2 \cdot \sigma^2}{2\cdot T}\bigg) \;.
\end{align*}
Taking logarithms and rearranging we get, for each $\lambda > 0$,
$$
\mathbb{E} [p_1 -p_{I_T}]
\le
 \frac{\log(K)}{\lambda} + \lambda \cdot  \frac{\sigma^2}{2\cdot T}\;,
$$
from which, taking $\lambda = \sqrt{\frac{2 \cdot \log(K)\cdot T}{\sigma^2}}$, we get
$$
\mathbb{E} [p_1 -p_{I_T}]
\le
\sigma \cdot \sqrt{2} \cdot \sqrt{\frac{\log(K)}{T}} = \sqrt{\frac{2 \cdot\log(K)}{T}}
\;.
$$